# Django finds two objects in a filter() query but fails to loop through them

Tags: django

Never had this happen before. The following is a method I've added to a model. It just checks that none of the LineItems related to it have a reconciliation_date set.

The method is always returning False so I added a few logger.warning() lines to see what is happening. As you can see in the image, the method executes, finds that the model object has two related line_items and then ignores the for loop. Very strange!

[image: Django finds two objects in a filter() query but fails to loop through them]

```
    @property
    def is_reconciled(self):
        """Checks if JournalEntry has reconciled lineitems"""
        logger.warning('Starting is_reconciled() model property..')
        line_items = LineItem.objects.filter(journal_entry=self.id)
        #logger.warning('Found ' + str(len(line_items)) + ' line items')
        for item in line_items:
            logger.warning('Doing loop 1. Line_item is '+ item)
            if item.reconciliation_date is not None:
                logger.warning('Reconciliation date is not none here')
                return True
        return False
```

Comment: I don't see a problem here - but you might be able to simplify this by moving the check into the database. Something like `return self.lineitem_set.filter(reconciliation_date__isnull=False).exists()` should do it.

Comment: Peter, that worked, thank you.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper just checked,  line_item is not defined

Comment: oh, yeah, that tracks. You meant something like `'Line_item is ' + item` in your logger warning. Or `for line_item in line_items:`